# How to split a CSV row so row[0] is the name and any remaining items are a tuple?

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have a csv file in which the first column is the name of a baseball player, and then each subsequent item in the file is a statistic. I'd like to be able to import the file so that the player name was equal to a tuple of the statistics.

Right now when I import the file using this code:

```
Orioles = file("Orioles.csv", "rU")
for row in Orioles:
    print row
```

I get something like this:

```
[Nick_Markakis, '.005', '.189', '.070', '.002', '.090']
[Adam_Jones, '.005', '.189', '.070', '.002', '.090']
```

I'd like to have the statistics be listed as floats rather than strings and be able to pull out the player name, and use it later, like this:

```
Nick_Markakis = ['.005', '.189', '.070', '.002', '.090']
Adam_Jones = ['.005', '.189', '.070', '.002', '.090']
```

Answer (score 4):

Having the player name be it's own variable is not as helpful as you might think:  you can't iterate over the collection (because there isn't one), your code is fixed and fragile (you have to add/remove lines when a player name is added or removed from your file, etc.

If, however, you have them in a dictionary -- well, now you can iterate, and you can still ask for players by name.

```
player_data = file("Orioles.csv", "rU")
orioles = dict()
for row in player_data:
    row = row.split(',')
    orioles[row[0]] = tuple(map(float, row[1:]))

print orioles.keys()
# ['Adam_Jones', 'Nick_Markakis']
print orioles['Adam_Jones']
# (0.005, 0.189, 0.07, 0.002, 0.09)
```

Rather than the `row.split(',')` trick above, you'll probably want to use the `csv` module in real code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the tip on the dictionary! Extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
Orioles = file("Orioles.csv", "rU")
stats = dict((row[0], map(float, row[1:])) for row in Orioles)
# In Python 2.7+: stats = {row[0]: map(float, row[1:]) for row in Orioles}
```

Now, you can access the stats like this:

```
print(sum(stats['Nick_Markakis'])) # 0.356
```

Comment: I would use `[float(stat) for stat in row[1:]]` instead of `map`, but this looks good.

Comment: @Wilduck `map` is actually faster by quite a bit (not that I'm suggesting premature optimization -- it's also quite easy to read)